# Is there a drawback to underlayment between multiple layers of subfloor?

Tags: floor, subfloor, underlayment

My upstairs sub flooring is 5/8" plywood, which is screwed to the joists. I want to add an additional 3/8" layer of plywood, followed by floating 1/2" bamboo flooring. I plan on using a 2mm underlayment between the second layer of plywood and the bamboo flooring.

Would it be OK to install a 2mm underlayment between the first (5/8") and second (3/8") layer of the subfloor?

Other than some additional expense, are there any downsides to this?

Also would I be correct in orienting the second layer of plywood so that the gaps between boards do NOT align with the first layer boards?

Comment: The 3/8" plywood itself would be underlayment. If the 2mm layer is below the 3/8" plywood, then technically the 2mm is not underlayment. You should be more specific about this 2mm. Is this a layer of sound dampening?

Comment: you can do it.  Your floor ends up slightly more bouncing but that is the general effect of underlay.  The floor manufacturers typically spec the compressive strength of the underlay so that you don't end up with so much deflection that you break the click lock of the floating floor.  is your floating floor tng with tng glue or is it a click lock?

Comment: @popham - it was just an idea that came to mind. Wondering if it might be worth it for additional sound deadening and eliminating potential squeaks. I plan to screw the 3/8" plywood down to the 5/8" layer of plywood.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - the floating floor will be click lock. Sounds like I probably want to skip doing a layer of underlayment material between the layers of subfloor. I'm not looking to add to the bounciness.

Comment: Is the 3/8" necessary for a floor elevation that you're targeting?

Comment: @popham - ideally yes. Would you suggest different course of action? My goal is to end up with the most solid feeling, squeak free floor possible, given that I’m working with initial subfloors that are using 5/8” plywood. I’ve already screwed the existing plywood to the joists. If adding a layer of 3/8” plywood, would you recommend screwing and gluing it down? Also would you suggest staggering the gaps of the 3/8” so that they don’t line up with the 5/8” sheets? Appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm not sure what answer to write since it's sort of an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info), with an as-of-yet unchallenged assertion that it'll do what's expected. I don't think it will.

Comment: There are several existing questions on the right way to double subfloor. That should not be tangled into this question, which should remain solely about the idea of using _flooring_ underlayment as a subfloor component.

Comment: @isherwood, thank you for your responses, could you elaborate. I'm not certain what "unchallenged assertion" you are referring to, as I made no assertions, I merely asked a question regarding the use of a layer of underlayment material between layers of plywood. Regardless as this time I plan to glue/screw the second layer of plywood directly to the first. Therefore my question at this time would be more of how much construction adhesive coverage to use for each 4x8 sheet of plywood?

Comment: Your assertion is that your plan to sandwich _flooring_ underlayment (as opposed to conventional plywood underlayment) _within the subfloor_ will provide the benefits you seem to assume.

Comment: @isherwood, I never asserted that was what I was going to do. I stated that I was planning on using underlayment between the second layer of subfloor (3/8 plywood) and the bamboo flooring.

I ASKED if installing a layer of underlayment between layers of plywood would be ok to do and subsequently stated that I was wondering if it would be worth it. I made no assumptions, which is of course why I posted the question.

Comment: Not to beat this ailing horse, but asking whether it's "ok" and for any "downsides" implies that you're beyond questioning whether it's even _going to accomplish the goal_.

Comment: You my friend seem to make many unsubstantiated assumptions. Thank you for your responses. Perhaps do you have any helpful suggestions? I assume that you are able to ascertain what it is that I'm trying to accomplish and that I am seeking advice from those whom would have more experience than me.

Comment: Is it "OK"? I'm sure it is. I think that the question we're trying to get at is what benefit do you expect to gain by doing so? If you'll address that, you'll probably get a "Yes, it'll achieve your goal", or "No, you're headed down the wrong path". Other than adding a few mills of thickness to the floor, I'm not sure what benefit you'd gain, but, once you've nailed down the 2nd layer of sub floor over it, I don't really see any downsides other than the added expense.

Comment: @FreeMan, thank you very much! The thought was to minimize noise transfer downstairs and subfloor squeaks. I know that a layer of sound deadening material (in this case underlayment) sandwiched between the layers of plywood will dampen sound transfer; however, I was uncertain of its practicality for this application. In an earlier response, Fresh Codemonger suggested that adding the underlayment between layers of plywood, would result in additional bounciness, which is undesirable, so I won't be doing that. I instead plan to glue/screw the 3/8 plywood down to the existing 5/8 plywood.

Comment: At this time what I could use most is any advice/tips from anyone who has done this. Obviously I don't want to finish the job and find that I didn't apply enough construction adhesive or I used a poor technique.

Comment: I seriously doubt you'll find anyone who has done this. As I've tried to get across, it's a very unorthodox approach. I'd bet real money that no flooring underlayment manufacturer will endorse it (which in itself isn't a problem for an innovator, but that's not what it was designed for). I don't think it'll do what you assume, and I _do_ think it'll introduce unwanted flex between layers of subfloor, possibly resulting in dimples at fastener locations.

Answer (score 1):

I always go to tiling sources for subfloor details. If you look at the specs for span rated plywood, you'll discover that it has the typical L/360 deflection limit, but they use 100 psf instead of the floor's 40 psf rating. I assume that this is to avoid squishiness under foot presses. I imagine that way back they measured the squishiness of an old floor built from 3/4" boards and conjured a spec to replicate the feel, but I'm just speculating.

The TCNA Handbook (a tiling source) has a 5/8" subfloor plus 1/2" underlayment spec for floor joists on 16" centers. I recall that Schluter (a tiling system manufacturer) has a spec for 3/8" underlayment, but that's below one of their Ditra products, so it's not applicable here. Operating within this context, I wouldn't spec 3/8" underlayment for new construction.

By gluing the subfloor and underlayment into a composite, you can still get the stiffness of a 5/8" subfloor plus 1/2" underlayment. I don't like it because it's extra work. Further, anybody who tries to remove the underlayment in the future is in for a big surprise. I would use the "premixed thinset" that tilers use ("mastic" or "organic adhesive" are other common names). A 3/16" v-notch trowel would be the tool to get a nice even distribution without too much thickness. Both the subfloor and the underlayment must be Exposure 1 rated (the "X" in CDX means Exposure 1, and OSB is generally Exposure 1 rated).

Your 2mm layer sounds like more cost and work. Additionally it would interfere with the composite floor if you use the 3/8" underlayment plus organic adhesive.

The typical detail of underlayment calls for 1/8" gaps between sheets and staggered to miss the subfloor joints. I think that the sheets tend to have a bit of extra thickness at the cuts, so I imagine that part of the justification is to avoid adding this extra thickness twice at the same spot. Additionally, the interior spans of plywood away from the ends have more stiffness than the end spans. The other justification for the staggered joints, I imagine, is to avoid stacking the underlayment's soft spans on top of the subfloor's soft spans.

The TCNA Handbook's F150 detail calls for 1/8" gaps between underlayment panels. It doesn't specify fasteners and it doesn't specify a fastener spacing. Every 8" sounds familiar.

And don't orient the underlayment incorrectly. Its face grain should run perpendicular to the joists. Just align the long edges of your underlayment parallel to the long edges of your subfloor, and you should be fine.